# Repopulating an HTML table on-the-fly

Tags: javascript, xml, json, xslt, xmlhttprequest

I have some simple XML like this:

```
<Tag>
<Keyphrases>
<Keyphrase Phrase = "This is phrase one"/>
<Keyphrase Phrase = "This is phrase two"/>
<Keyphrase Phrase = "This is phrase three"/>
</Keyphrases>
</Tag>
```

And I have an XSLT that contains:

```
[...]

<table id="realtimetable">
<xsl:apply-templates select="Tag/Keyphrases"/>
</table>

[...]

<!-- Build KeyPhrase Rows -->
<xsl:template match="Tag/Keyphrases">
<xsl:for-each select="Keyphrase">
<tr><td>
<xsl:value-of select="@Phrase" />
</td></tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

But now I wish to update the content of that table on the fly. I understand I can use XMLHttpRequest() to fetch new data.

However, I do not know what format to use for those updates or how to insert the new data into the table.

I can supply the updates in XML. But can I re-use my existing XSLT template to parse it and repopulate the displayed table? This seems elegant and tidy but is it possible and if so, how would I do it?

If that's not possible, I suppose I could write the Javascript to parse the XML and update the table myself. That sounds like a lot of grunt work :-(

So I was also considering responding to the XMLHTTPRequest in JSON format. I think it may be easier to process JSON that it is to parse the XML.

But what should my JSON document look like and how do I write the JavaScript to process the JSON and repopulate the table?

Asumming I have a clean (error checked) response from XMLHttpRequest() what do I do here?

```
function ProcessUpdate() 
{
}
```

I would prefer to avoid using any libraries such as jQuery for this project.

#### Update:

Thank you for all the responses. Some comments and clarification:

1. The reasons for avoiding jQuery et al at this point are... a) This project already has a bunch of other dependencies and I'm trying to limit the growth of that rats nest. b) I tend to learn new stuff more effectively with a bottoms-up approach. When I understand the lower-level atomic operations I feel much more comfortable using high-level libraries to do the grunt work for me.
2. The table in question is very small and simple. Therefore I'm inclined to recreate the entire table from scratch on each update. There's really no need to deal with the complexity of selective updates.
3. Dimitre: your XSL looks fascinating and I will definitely spend some time digesting that. However, what I don't understand (at all) is how to invoke this update. i.e. How would I trigger this re-transformation from the JavaScript?

Comment: Why would you prefer writing something yourself to using jQuery?  What is your objection there - dependencies, size, lack of familiarity, etc?

Comment: I don't understand the chain. Suppose an original XML document. This will be transformed with your XSLT stylesheet resulting in an XHTML table. Now, will the new requested XML document cointain previous and newer data or just only newer data?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete and natural XSLT solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd strongly recommend using JSON instead of XML for this task -- as you've already realized, you probably don't want to be in the business of parsing XML on the client side.

Once you have your XHR response as JSON data, you can use client-side templating to turn the response into markup, then place the markup on your page. If you change your mind about jQuery, then jQuery has a templating plugin ([jQuery.tmpl](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl)) you can use to accomplish this; there's also the standalone [mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/), and the extremely lightweight [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/). You can of course write your own templating code, too. All of the client-side templating tools follow the same general principle (though with different syntax, so make sure to read the docs), taking a template such as:

```
<p>Hello, my name is ${firstName} ${lastName}</p>
```

... and then taking some data, such as:

```
{ "firstName" : "Rebecca", "lastName" : "Murphey" }
```

... and then combining them to create the desired output, which can then be added to your DOM.

If you're trying to update an existing table, you can generate the HTML for the full table, and then remove the old table and insert the new one. Alternately, you could just append new rows -- it depends on the exact nature of what you're trying to do.

Finally: as the commenter mentioned, I'd reconsider your opposition to using a library of any sort unless there are truly compelling reasons not to. There's no glory in reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at how I do it in my library if you want, [this](https://github.com/Wolfy87/Spark/blob/master/spark-dev.js#L1939) function calls [this](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/raw/master/json2.js) lovely set of functions for dealing with JSON. And [this](https://github.com/Wolfy87/Spark/blob/master/spark-dev.js#L1700) function is used for making AJAX calls, I have done **a lot** of research into cross browser compatibility so it makes a good example.

If you are using PHP then you can encode the data as JSON and pass it back to your JS like so:

```
echo json_encode($myData);
```

I don't think this has awnsered your questions but I do think it has helped you get closer.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is an XSLT transformation with updates accepted as an external parameter. It operates on the current table as the source XML document**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"
 exclude-result-prefixes="ext">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pReps">
  <updates>
   <replace line="2">This is new phrase two</replace>
   <delete line="3"/>
   <insert-before line="1">This is phrase zero (new)</insert-before>
   <insert-after line="4">This is phrase five (new)</insert-after>
  </updates>
 </xsl:param>

 <xsl:variable name="vReps"
      select="ext:node-set($pReps)/*/*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="tr">
  <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="not(position()=$vReps/@line)">
    <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
     <xsl:variable name="vPos" select="position()"/>
     <xsl:variable name="vupdCommand"
          select="$vReps[@line=$vPos]"/>
     <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="$vupdCommand[self::replace]">
        <tr><td><xsl:value-of select="$vupdCommand"/></td></tr>
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:when test="$vupdCommand[self::insert-before]">
        <tr><td><xsl:value-of select="$vupdCommand"/></td></tr>
        <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:when test="$vupdCommand[self::insert-after]">
        <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
        <tr><td><xsl:value-of select="$vupdCommand"/></td></tr>
       </xsl:when>
     </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the current table**:

```
<tabe id="realtimetable">
 <tr><td>This is phrase one</td></tr>
 <tr><td>This is phrase two</td></tr>
 <tr><td>This is phrase three</td></tr>
 <tr><td>This is phrase four</td></tr>
</tabe>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<tabe id="realtimetable">
   <tr>
      <td>This is phrase zero (new)</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>This is phrase one</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>This is new phrase two</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>This is phrase four</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>This is phrase five (new)</td>
   </tr>
</tabe>
```

Comment: OP wrote: *your XSL looks fascinating and I will definitely spend some time digesting that. However, what I don't understand (at all) is how to invoke this update. i.e. How would I trigger this re-transformation from the JavaScript?*